# MongoDB : operation after lookup takes a long time

Tags: mongodb

I have a speed problem on aggregation $lookup with big collections.

Here is two requests. Both consist on a $match. This operation is very fast. Then I do a $lookup, which is fast too.

After that, I do an operation on the $lookup result. In the first case, this operation is very fast, on the second it is very slow.

The first and fast request :

```
db.getCollection('table1').aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "type": "test",
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "table2",
            "localField": "name",
            "foreignField": "name",
            "as": "lookup_names"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "names": {
                // reduce on lookup_names is very fast
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$lookup_names",
                    "initialValue": ""
                    "in": {
                        "$concat": ["$$value.name", ".", "$$this.name"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The second and slow request :

```
db.getCollection('table1').aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "type": "test"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "table2",
            "localField": "name",
            "foreignField": "name",
            "as": "lookup_names"
        }
    },
    {
        // match on lookup_names is very slow
        "$match": {
            "lookup_names.name": "test"
        }
    }
])
```

Can someone explain me why the second request is very slow ? And maybe give me a solution to make it faster ?

Comment: They are not doing the same thing. So basically they don't compare at all. The `$match` in your example is selecting "documents" and NOT "array members" ( very commonly miscontrued ). The `$reduce` simply acts on "array members" within each document. Also **fast** and **slow** are really subjective without context. But for example if you had a couple of million documents, then a `$match` on a non-indexed field would be expected to be **very slow**. And yes at that stage in a pipeline you **cannot** use an index. Too broad anyway.

Comment: because in the second query you are processing the extra filtering